# SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using the following class.phpmailer.php file as part of a registration system on a PHP site but I am getting the error below.

I have put the top of my phpmailer file in along with the error message at the bottom which I am seeing once I submit the form on the live web site.

```
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PROPERTIES, PUBLIC
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /**
   * Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low).
   * @var int
   */
  public $Priority          = 3;
  /**
   * Sets the CharSet of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $CharSet           = 'iso-8859-1';
  /**
   * Sets the Content-type of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $ContentType       = 'text/plain';
  /**
   * Sets the Encoding of the message. Options for this are
   *  "8bit", "7bit", "binary", "base64", and "quoted-printable".
   * @var string
   */
  public $Encoding          = '8bit';
  /**
   * Holds the most recent mailer error message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $ErrorInfo         = '';
  /**
   * Sets the From email address for the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $From              = 'noreply@domain.co.uk';
  /**
   * Sets the From name of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $FromName          = 'Name';
  /**
   * Sets the Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.  If not empty,
   * will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Sender            = 'noreply@domain.co.uk';
  /**
   * Sets the Subject of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Subject           = '';
  /**
   * Sets the Body of the message.  This can be either an HTML or text body.
   * If HTML then run IsHTML(true).
   * @var string
   */
  public $Body              = '';
  /**
   * Sets the text-only body of the message.  This automatically sets the
   * email to multipart/alternative.  This body can be read by mail
   * clients that do not have HTML email capability such as mutt. Clients
   * that can read HTML will view the normal Body.
   * @var string
   */
  public $AltBody           = '';
  /**
   * Stores the complete compiled MIME message body.
   * @var string
   * @access protected
   */
  protected $MIMEBody       = '';
  /**
   * Stores the complete compiled MIME message headers.
   * @var string
   * @access protected
   */
  protected $MIMEHeader     = '';
  /**
   * Stores the complete sent MIME message (Body and Headers)
   * @var string
   * @access protected
  */
  protected $SentMIMEMessage     = '';
  /**
   * Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of
   * characters.
   * @var int
   */
  public $WordWrap          = 0;
  /**
   * Method to send mail: ("mail", "sendmail", or "smtp").
   * @var string
   */
  public $Mailer            = 'smtp';
  /**
   * Sets the path of the sendmail program.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Sendmail          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
  /**
   * Path to PHPMailer plugins.  Useful if the SMTP class
   * is in a different directory than the PHP include path.
   * @var string
   */
  public $PluginDir         = '';
  /**
   * Sets the email address that a reading confirmation will be sent.
   * @var string
   */
  public $ConfirmReadingTo  = '';
  /**
   * Sets the hostname to use in Message-Id and Received headers
   * and as default HELO string. If empty, the value returned
   * by SERVER_NAME is used or 'localhost.localdomain'.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Hostname          = 'mail.domain.co.uk';
  /**
   * Sets the message ID to be used in the Message-Id header.
   * If empty, a unique id will be generated.
   * @var string
   */
  public $MessageID         = '';
```

All has been working fine until recently.

I have tried various changes to the script but just can't seem to fix this error.

The error I am getting is:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "501 <>: missing or malformed local part " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "501 <>: missing or malformed local part " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:501 <>: missing or malformed local part 
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part 
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed:
SMTP server error: <>: missing or malformed local part
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old and buggy version of PHPMailer. [Update to the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on the examples provided with it.